# Custom Color defined in Color.kt is not appearing in MaterialTheme.colors

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I've defined a custom color in Color.kt

`val Colors.bgray: Color get() = Color(0xFF8ECE45)`

But it's not appearing as  `MaterialTheme.colors.bgray`

I've tried adding `@Composable` notation above `get()`

[Unresolved reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zolWG.png)

Comment: Check this answer please: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66931856/13089092

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
val Colors.bgray: Color @Composable get() = Color(0xFF8ECE45)

Box(Modifier.background(MaterialTheme.colors.bgray))
```

Or:

```
val bgray: Color  get() = Color(0xFF8ECE45)

Box(Modifier.background(bgray))
```

Comment: thanks. Second one is working, but first one is not. Why can't I access the color via MaterialTheme.colors.bgray ?