# Jetpack Compose add custom dark/light colors?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, material-components-android

Wh can create dark and light color palette, it's ok.
[image]

But it has only 12 colors.
How to add more custom colors for the light and dark palette?

Comment: have you tried [migrating to Material3](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/designsystems/material2-material3) it contains 29 colors built-in

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use `CompositionLocalProvider` for that.

1. Create a data class that will contain what you want to use and its `staticCompositionLocalOf`. For example `CustomColorsPalette.kt`:

```kotlin
@Immutable
data class CustomColorsPalette(
    val custom1OnBackground: Color = Color.Unspecified,
    val custom2OnBackground: Color = Color.Unspecified,
    val custom1OnSurface: Color = Color.Unspecified,
    val custom2OnSurface: Color = Color.Unspecified,
    val other1: Color = Color.Unspecified,
    val other2: Color = Color.Unspecified
)

val LocalCustomColorsPalette = staticCompositionLocalOf { CustomColorsPalette() }
```

2. Create different variations, based on light or dark theme:

```kotlin
val OnLightCustomColorsPalette = CustomColorsPalette(
    custom1OnBackground = Color(color = 0xFF1A237E),
    custom2OnBackground = Color(color = 0xFF1B5E20),
    custom1OnSurface = Color(color = 0xFFE53935),
    custom2OnSurface = Color(color = 0xFFD81B60),
    other1 = Color(color = 0xFF006064),
    other2 = Color(color = 0xFF643700)
)

val OnDarkCustomColorsPalette = CustomColorsPalette(
    custom1OnBackground = Color(color = 0xFF1E88E5),
    custom2OnBackground = Color(color = 0xFF43A047),
    custom1OnSurface = Color(color = 0xFFC62828),
    custom2OnSurface = Color(color = 0xFFAD1457),
    other1 = Color(color = 0xFF00897B),
    other2 = Color(color = 0xFF896200)
)
```

3. Use the logic in the `Compose` theme to decide when to use one or the other:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun AppTheme(
    darkTheme: Boolean = isSystemInDarkTheme(),
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    val colors = if (darkTheme) DarkColorPalette else LightColorPalette
    
    val customColorsPalette =
        if (darkTheme) OnDarkCustomColorsPalette
        else OnLightCustomColorsPalette

    CompositionLocalProvider(
        LocalCustomColorsPalette provides customColorsPalette
    ) {
        MaterialTheme(
            colors = colors,
            typography = Typography,
            shapes = Shapes,
            content = content
        )
    }
}
```

---

It is now possible to use these colors directly from the composable code with with `LocalCustomColorsPalette.current`:

```kotlin
Text(
    text = "Anything...",
    color = LocalCustomColorsPalette.current.custom1OnBackground
)
```

More information about `CompositionLocalProvider` on [docs](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/compositionlocal).

---

**Bonus**

It is possible to change the call to `LocalCustomColorsPalette.current` to make it similar to what we have with the other properties of `MaterialTheme`. To do this, you can add the following code (it could be in the same file as the first step):

```kotlin
// ...

val MaterialTheme.customColorsPalette: CustomColorsPalette
    @Composable
    @ReadOnlyComposable
    get() = LocalCustomColorsPalette.current
```

And now you can use like this:

```kotlin
Text(
    text = "Anything...",
    color = MaterialTheme.customColorsPalette.custom1OnBackground
)
```

Comment: Hello. I'm trying to follow your solution but MaterialTheme( colors = colors, this colors is giving me an error that require Colors and found CustomColorsPalette

Comment: @S.P. MaterialTheme in Material3 has different constructor, you need to provide these: `MaterialTheme(colorScheme = colorScheme, typography = Typography, content = content)`

Comment: I found the updated answer (for Material3) here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77041136/1101730

Comment: This is definitely correct answer and there are couple of ways of achieving this via Composition local. This is exactly what Material Theme itself is written like. i followed a blog just for colors (not typography or shapes) and acheived it easily.
https://betterprogramming.pub/jetpack-compose-custom-themes-b1836877981d

Answer (score 0):

In your `Theme.kt` file, you can add as many custom colors as you want using the `isSystemInDarkTheme()` function to define light/dark versions as follow:

```kotlin
val ColorScheme.customColor1: Color
    @Composable
    get() = if(isSystemInDarkTheme()) Color.Green else Color.Red

val ColorScheme.customColor2: Color
    @Composable
    get() = if(isSystemInDarkTheme()) Color.Blue else Color.Cyan
```

Use them in your code as all the other Material3 colors:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun Testing() {
    Column {
        Text(
            text = "A text with my custom color 1", 
            color = colorScheme.customColor1
        )
        Text(
            text = "A text with my custom color 2", 
            color = colorScheme.customColor2
        )
    }
}
```