# How to extend ColorScheme in Material3?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, material-design

In material2, we add more colors as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65994303), but how to do that for Material3?

Comment: I guess the same way, just make it an extension property of `ColorScheme` instead of `Colors`?